# where to find snowball.dll that is compatible with Lucene 3.0

Tags: lucene, snowballanalyzer

I am using Lucene 3.0 and I need Snowball analyzer for stemming that is compatible with Lucene 3.0. I searched in Google for an hour and I was unable to find a credible source. Please suggest a trusted location from which I can download snowball.dll  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Lucene 3.0.3 docs, SnowballAnalyzer is in:

```
org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.SnowballAnalyzer
```

with documentation at:

https://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_3/api/contrib-snowball/org/apache/lucene/analysis/snowball/SnowballAnalyzer.html

The Lucene download archives are at:

http://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/java/

Near as I can tell, SnowballAnalyzer is part of the base Lucene package (i.e. not in `contrib`).

Comment: Thanks Mark, It did not occur to me.